# Spring 3.2.0 @Autowired dosn't work null pointer

Tags: spring

i have a problem.The annotation @Autowired throws Eception null poinetr.
My service

```
package service;

     @Service
        public class PrincipaleService {
        ....
        public void importer(String path) throws IOException{
    ...
        }
```

my class

```
package managedbean;

    @Component
    @ManagedBean(name="Principale")
    @SessionScoped
    public class pricipaleManagedBean {
    @Autowired
        PrincipaleService principaleservice;
    ...
      principaleservice.importer(path);
    ...
    }
```

importer(path) throws null pointer but if i do principaleservice=new PrincipaleService() every thing work well.
Why @Autowired doesn't work.Help please

Comment: and when i add to my application context         <context:component-scan base-package="managedbean" />
managedbean is the package of principalemanagedbean i got 404 la resource demandé est indisponible

Comment: Is PrincipaleService class present in managedbean package? or a child package? Add your package statement to the code in question. Looks like package of PrincipaleService is not added to scan.

Comment: `@AutoWired` won't work with `@ManagedBean`

Comment: a child packackage. i added my package statement to my code in question.